# Resolved: PayPal Adaptive Payments Authentication failed

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have registered on PayPal Sandbox, then I added Seller Preconfigured test account. As for ApplicationId, I used few ones found on Web. Finally, triggering Preapproval, I'm having error in response:

```
Array
(
    [RESPONSEENVELOPE.TIMESTAMP] => 2011-12-26T19:39:54.500-08:00
    [RESPONSEENVELOPE.ACK] => Failure
    [RESPONSEENVELOPE.CORRELATIONID] => a052cd3abd4ea
    [RESPONSEENVELOPE.BUILD] => 2279004
    [ERROR(0).ERRORID] => 520003
    [ERROR(0).DOMAIN] => PLATFORM
    [ERROR(0).SUBDOMAIN] => Application
    [ERROR(0).SEVERITY] => Error
    [ERROR(0).CATEGORY] => Application
    [ERROR(0).MESSAGE] => Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
)
```

PHP code:

```
$URL = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval'
    .'?startingDate='.date('Y-m-d\Z')
    .'&endingDate='.date('Y-m-d\Z', strtotime('+1 year'))
    .'&currencyCode=USD'
    .'&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=500.00'
    .'&maxAmountPerPayment=200.00'
    .'&maxNumberOfPayments=30'
    .'&senderEmail=user@domain.com'
    .'&cancelUrl=http://example.com/cancel'
    .'&returnUrl=http://example.com'
    .'&pinType=NOT_REQUIRED'
    .'&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
    , array(
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID' => 'xxxx'
        , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD' => 'xxxx'
        , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        , 'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T'
        , 'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT' => 'NV'
        , 'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'NV'
    )
);  
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseAr = explode('&', $response);
$parsedResponseAr = array();
foreach($responseAr as $i => $value) {
    $tmpAr = explode('=', $value);
    if(!empty($tmpAr))
        $parsedResponseAr[strtoupper($tmpAr[0])] = urldecode($tmpAr[1]);
}
print_r($parsedResponseAr);
```

Could that be because of wrong App Ids? Do I have to register my App first to get App Id to use it in Sandbox?

Edit: I found the reason: the format of headers array was incorrect.
It should be:

```
array(
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: xxx'
    , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: xxxx'
    , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: xxxxxxxx'
    , 'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T'
    , 'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
    , 'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ERROR(0).MESSAGE] => Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
```

bit of a give away!

Comment: I know, but I use the credential from PayPal and they are correct. Does it indicate the key is incorrect? `[ERROR(0).CATEGORY] => Application`

Comment: API credentials are incorrect means what it says, maybe a typo by yourself, re-check the credentials, If all else fails create a new user account(sandbox)

Comment: Exactly the same error under newly created PayPal Sandbox account... I think I have to register our App first.

Comment: Could be an IPN failure....Those things need you to verify your bank details and stuff, check your sandbox credentials, make sure you are verified... {not sure if this is a paypal glitch or localhost acting the maggot }

Comment: I have not entered any bank info on Sandbox

Comment: I found the reason: the format of headers array was incorrect.
It should be:

    `array(
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: xxx'
  , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: xxxx'
  , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: xxxxxxxx'
  , 'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T'
  , 'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
  , 'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
 )`

Comment: Yes, as I said - headers were set wrongly and now I have it working... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi all, I have the authentication failed error. I got the API from paypal site. I created the sandbox accounts in developer site. I have checked the headers too. But I could not solve this error. please suggest me.

Comment: Same here, did anybody find out why the app-id can be invalid?